# How can we generate a shared key from two key pairs for an ECC implementation?

Tags: elliptic-curves

[image]

This is the diagram of an ecc implementation here that needs to generate the shared key, how can it be done?

Comment: i'm a newbie that's why posted many question mark instead of one. if you find that offensive then i'm sorry.

Comment: I have removed the superfluous question marks because from what I could tell they added no value to the question as opposed to a simple question mark (and the question looks better with a single one I think). No offense was taken at all by anyone I strongly believe.

Comment: Shared secret is just one private key multiplied by the other's public *point* (public key is usually the x coordinate of that point). Since they are both starting from the same base point the result is the same for both (base point * one private key * the other private key).

Answer (score 2):

The diagram leaves out something (rather assumes it implicitly), which is that you and the recipient have agreed upon curve parameters / a standardized curve with which to perform key exchange. We can derive the shared key as follows once we agree upon parameters (this method is basically elliptic curve Diffie Hellman):

1. Use the RNG to generate an integer $d \in \mathbb{Z}_q$ where $q$ is the order of the generator point $G$ of the curve (technically $d$ can be arbitrarily large but there's no advantage to this).
2. Your ECC key pair is then $(d, Q)$ where $Q = d*G$. $d$ is the private key, $Q$ is the public key. Note that $Q$ is a point on the curve.
3. Given the recipients public key $R$ (also a point on the curve) compute $S = d * R$. $S$ is the shared secret. (Note that if $e$ is the recipients private key that means $R = e * G$, and thus $S = d * e * G$, meaning if we send the recipient our public key $Q$ they can also derive the secret $S = e * Q = e * d * G$).

Now we have shared key material we can pass into a KDF to derive symmetric keys.

Comment: Isn't Q the public key? How come R became the public key? What is R?

Comment: $Q$ is your public key, $R$ is the recipients (the person you want to create a shared key with) public key.